# How to enable nVidia graphics

Tags: nvidia, graphics

I have Aero 15x v8 with nVidia 1070 and intel integrated graphics.
I have gone to "additional drivers" and selected proprietary nvidia-driver-390.
I applied the changes and re-booted.

when I terminal > prime-select query, I get "nvidia"
however, settings>details: shows graphics "Intel HD Graphics"

Which is actually being used ??
How do I make sure I'm using Intel graphics for battery savings but then switch to nvidia for games ?

also, The nvidia-settings app does not show any option for PRIME profiles